# What is the scope for Auto Post on Google +?

Tags: scope, oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-oauth

What is the scope for Auto Post my messages in the google plus account of my users ?

Thank you,

Comment: you cant post to Google+ using the API therefore there is no scope.

Comment: I don't need autorisation for post the messages ? I'm looking for to post 8 différents messages in different moment with only one authorization